# TreeMap collection views iterators time-complexity?

Tags: java, time-complexity, treemap

Time-complexity of all 3 collection view iterators for *HashMap* (`myHashMap.entrySet().iterator().next()` and `myHashMap.keySet().iterator().next()` and `myHashMap.values().iterator().next()`) is well-documented in javadoc, it is *O(n+c)* for all those 3 iterators (n is number of mappings, c is capacity that is physical number of buckets in hashtable).

But what about respective 3 iterators of 3 respective TreeMap collection views? Nothing is said in official javadoc. What are their complexities? I did look in SE8 source code but I cannot judge from there.

Comment: Federico Peralta Schaffner comment to this SO question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53667320/all-set-and-map-classes-and-all-respective-iterators-next-time-complexity-s implies log(n) for all three TreeMap collection view iterators - as an opinion

Comment: @Holger I think he is talking about one `next()` call.

Comment: @ZhaoGang exactly. And that’s not what the Javadoc is talking about.

Comment: For a TreeMap, forming the collection view will be O(n) and iterating over each element will be in total O(n). O(2n) will turn out to be O(n) in essence. Correct? (Considering Full iteration)

Comment: @Ankur Creating the collection view is just creating object wrappers and setting up some links, so it's `O(1)`. Then, as it's a *view* (i.e. not a copy of the actual entries), fetching each entry via `iterator.next()` might have some hidden costs. In the case of `TreeMap`, I think it would need to reach the lowest entry, i.e. the leftmost leaf of the tree, which would be `O(logN)` because the tree is balanced. Then, for the rest of the entries, it would be just a red-black tree traversal, which would yield `O(1)` for each fetched entry, totalling `logN + N - 1 ~ O(N)` for the whole traversal.

Comment: Well I suspected the same about forming collection view, but not so sure about going to the left most leaf node first. That shouldn’t be required I think.

Answer (score 4):

Try to answer this based on these great comments:

1. One single `next()` call has a totally different time complexity compared with the whole iterating process.
2. TreeMap in Java is based on Red-Black Tree, which is a balanced binary search tree.

Refer to https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html

3. Iterating a whole TreeMap should have the same time complexity as traversing the Red-Balck Tree(For pre-order in-order or post-order traveral). So time complexity should be `O(n)` where `n` is the key(or value, or key-value mapping) count.
4. For a single `next` call, we can do it in `O(1)`. If a whole `O(n)` time complexity is true, this should be trivial.

Comment: There is no next() in TreeMap. Is there a linked tree map in which we can iterate to next element in O(1)?

Comment: @NathanB By saying `next()` , I mean `iterator.next()` on `entrySet()`, `keySet()`, and `values()`.  There should be no linked tree map, we only have `LinkedHashMap`.

Comment: The problem with LinkedHashMap is that it is not sorted by the key.

Comment: @NathanB That is true.  Are you asking that why the time complexity is `O(1)` for the `iterator.next()` function?